# Can't create a Vue ref with a possibly null type

Tags: typescript, vue.js

In Vue v3, I want to create a ref with a type that is possibly null. In my app, it represents data that starts out null until it finishes loading.

As a contrived example:

```
const firstRef: Ref<{ key: number } | null> = ref(null);

// This should give an error because firstRef.value might be null, but it only errors at runtime
const sum: number = firstRef.value.key + 1;
```

Whenever I hover over the type of `firstRef` in VSCode, it always shows the type as `Ref<{ key: number }>` without the `| null`. Am I doing something wrong? Or is it impossible to create a possibly-null ref for some reason?

Comment: this is normal,  `null + 1` will always throw an error

Comment: @davidr I know, but I want to be forced by the type checker to check for null values in my code. I should have to do something like `(firstRef.value?.key ?? 0) + 1` to keep TypeScript happy. But it blindly lets me try to add one to null, which it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was unrelated to Vue. The issue was not having `"strict": true` set in my `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json`.